# How to Update VS 2015 Cordova Node?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am having a problem with `VS2015 Cordova` and `NPM`.  I am trying to download the latest version of Angular2 using `package.json`

```
{
"name": "BlankCordovaApp5-jspm",
"version": "1.0.0",
"dependencies": {
   "systemjs": "0.19.4",
   "angular2": "2.0.0-alpha.42"
},
  "devDependencies": {

}
}
```

However, when I do I get the following error:
[image]

It would seem like the `npmjs` would be causing the problem, but the issue is an outdated VS2015 `Node` and `NPM`.  If I download the latest version of `Node` and then move the $(path) up or add the node folder to external tools, Angular 2 can now be downloaded.

[image]

Unfortunately, I now get the following errors:
[image]

**What are the steps to updating Visual Studio Cordova's Node and NPM and not get errors?**

Comment: What happens when you do "npm install angular2@2.0.0-alpha.42" from the command prompt?  Visual Studio uses your globally installed version of Node.js and npm.  Note: Be sure you are using Cordova 5.3.3 or higher if you install Node.js 4.0.0 particularly on OSX with the remotebuild agent.  Type node --version from the command prompt to see what you are running and npm --version to see that. Download and install the latest Node.js from the site and VS should use it.

Comment: Oh wait - You're looking at bower/npm support.  Cordova uses the globally installed version but it appears this support does not.  Question still is valid - Are you on Node 4.0.0+?  There's known compatibility issues with it - you may want to try 0.12.x to see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Chuck, thanks for the help.  

I'm was using Node Version 4.2.1, NPM 3.3.6 and Cordova 5.3.3.  I downloaded Node.js v0.12.0 from [https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ ](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ ) and I still have the same problems. Is it possible I'm using the wrong location for Node/NPM?  ![](https://gyazo.com/1c9a3c9ec3241e5908a1533b664cf90c.png) Note: VS2015 is using my System Properties >Environmental Variable > Path for NPM.

Comment: The problem likely is with NPM 3 which made some pretty major changes to how NPM works.  Now that you've downgraded node, can you type npm --version to see what version you are on?  You still may be on the upgraded version.  Failing that, this is a bug with ASP.NET's support for Node and NPM - there may not be a workaround until a fix is available.

Comment: Typing npm --version I get `2.5.1`  I had removed node using 'Add or Remove Programs' and then reinstalled.  It looks like VS2015 is using 
`node -v v0.10.31 npm -v 1.4.9`   As a work around for installing Angular2, I'll use npm install and PowerShell. However, I'm thinking the real work around would be to use JSPM?

Comment: Have you tried Bower?

Comment: Unfortunately, bower only seems to have angular 1.0.  When I type angular2 I get version 1.4.7 which is Angular 1. 
      "dependencies": {
       "angular2": "1.4.7"
       }

Answer (score 4):

Probably this can help you to update npm:

http://jameschambers.com/2015/09/upgrading-npm-in-visual-studio-2015/

and https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade

and if you update Node.js to 4.x, which makes sense, use the x86 variant
and go through this:
http://buli.waw.pl/update-node-js-integrated-with-visual-studio-2015/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the links! The two links are great and do a good job at explaining the problem.  Since VS2015 Node tools are internal, it's important that updating node keeps VS2015 stable.

Have you tried the npm-windows-upgrade?  Notice any stability problems?  I'll try it at the end of the day so when it breaks at least I have some work done :-)

Comment: I tryd the npm upgrad and works without problems for me
would be great to get a "mark as answer" ;-)

Comment: It works.  I did the npm-windows-upgrade, updated node.js to 4.2.1 and added the node location to Tools > options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools.  My previous version on build `Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (ia32) and npm.` and now `Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.2.1 (ia32) and npm.`  I hope it's stable.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.  When I restarted VS2015 I now get the following error when I open a project.  `Error - Cannot load global packages`.  Unfortunately, it's not working for me.

Comment: Did you clean the Node/NPM cache ? what could help (is mentioned in one of the links) is to delete de npm_modules folder in the project (not visible in Visual Studio normally). It then should restore the right package versions. It's also important, that the path to Node (eg C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs) is on top of External Web Tools List

Comment: npm cache clean

npm update -g  (update all existing global packages)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working.  I did the following: npm-windows-upgrade, updated node.js to 4.2.1 and added the node location to Tools > options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools (top position), cleared cache, deleted npm_modules folder. Screen shot [https://gyazo.com/8da84ccad7cbed0dc3cf885f1a1a0d20](https://gyazo.com/8da84ccad7cbed0dc3cf885f1a1a0d20)

Comment: look, if you found this package:  [project_root]\node_modules\aurelia-cli\node_modules\npm
If yes delete it

Comment: `[project_root]\node_modules\aurelia-cli\node_modules\npm ` doesn't exist in my project.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time to diagnose.  If anyone else is successfully, please add a comment.

Comment: Well DeanB_Develop... If you don't have the time to diagnose.. why another should have time to do this for you and how he can help you without knowing more details about your environment ;-) ?

Comment: To clarify, the issue I was having had to do with the latest version of Node & VS2015. I realize now it's a nice to have, but not critical or a problem. When Microsoft's @Chuck Lantz says ` there may not be a workaround until a fix is available` (see comments from original question above), my VS2015 currently works and I can use TACO as an alternative, then I'm OK with not finding a solution to a issue I was unsuccessful at diagnosing.  If someone has had problems with NODE and solved the problem with the current latest version of VS2015 community then add a comment.